# why openni packages are outdated?

Tags: openni

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
Recently i have immigrated to ubuntu 12.04 for installing ros-fuerte and also using up to date versions of openni packages! but i saw that they are still outdated!
the current release of openni is 1.5.2.23 and PrimeSense Nite is 1.5.2.21 but in ROS repositories its current version for openni is 1.4 and PrimeSense Nite is 1.3!!
The Newest stable version of Nite does not need Calibration pose any more and its really great!

i dont know why these packages aren't updated yet!!!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39332/why-openni-packages-are-outdated?/) by [Alireza](https://answers.ros.org/users/1637/alireza/) on ROS Answers with karma: 717 on 2012-07-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Probably the maintainers of the openni ros packages didn't have time to update yet. Feel free to file a request at the corresponding [issue tracker](https://kforge.ros.org/openni/trac), ideally with a patch attached if necessary.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-07-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3